# Parsing RSS XML with angular and x2js then using with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, rss

Hi hoping someone can help. I've been racking my brain for a few days trying to figure this out.

I'm trying to parse an xml rss file with angular and x2js to return only the **item** objects. It's formatted like:

```
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" 
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
   xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
   <title>Test Title</title>
   <link>
     https:somelocation.com
   </link>
   <description>List Title 1</description>
   <pubDate>Wed, 26 Apr 2017 13:04:51 GMT</pubDate>
   <dc:date>2017-04-26T13:04:51Z</dc:date>
   <item>
     <title>Test Title 1</title>
     <link>
      https://plnkr.co
     </link>
     <description>
      <DIV> <P>Some description text</P> </DIV>
     </description>
    <pubDate>Wed, 26 Apr 2017 13:04:51 GMT</pubDate>
    <guid>
      https://plnkr.co
    </guid>
    <dc:date>2017-04-26T13:04:51Z</dc:date>
  </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

I can return results but when I try to ng-repeat in my markup it's iterating over everything in the channel causing empty list objects to appear in the results. Here is my html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
   <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" 
    src="https://code.angularjs.org/latest/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="xml2Json.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="listController">
   <ul ng-repeat="item in list">
    <li ng-repeat="i in item">
    <h2><a href="{{i.link}}">{{i.title}}</a></h2>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>

</html>
```

And here are my scripts:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('listController', function($scope,$http){

  $http.get('rssFeed.xml', {
    transformResponse: function (data) {
     var x2js = new X2JS();
     var listData = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
     return listData.rss.channel.item;
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response, status){    
     $scope.list = response; 
   }, function errorCallback(response, status){
      console.log('Request failed' + status);
  });

});
```

The plunkr is located here: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MBAYhvVYE2rCZ2eJLfaC?p=preview)

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Hi Amit, yes. I will answer and approve the question shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to return and close this. Answering in case it's helpful to anyone else running into this issue.
I updated my html by removing "ng-repeat" attribute from the ul tag and replaced the li ng-repeat with it. I also updated the the script by changing `$scope.list = response;` to `$scope.list = response.data;`. By doing this I was able to avoid iterating over everything under the channel tag in the rss and only target the items themselves. See code below and here's an updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ORiL92YOtwFm25CFA4dx?p=preview).

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">
         <head>
          <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" 
          src="https://code.angularjs.org/latest/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="xml2Json.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
          <script src="script.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="listController">
         <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="item in list">
           <h2><a href="{{i.link}}">{{i.title}}</a></h2>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my updated script

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('listController', function($scope,$http){

      $http.get('rssFeed.xml', {
        transformResponse: function (data) {
         var x2js = new X2JS();
         var listData = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
         return listData.rss.channel.item;
        }
      }).then(function successCallback(response, status){    
          $scope.list = response.data; 
       }, function errorCallback(response, status){
          console.log('Request failed' + status);
      });

    });
```